# How to organize route dependencies in Node.js / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I understand how to export routes to an index.js file but the problem I am having is I don't understand how to properly reference those external route dependencies without pasting them to the top of the file.

In other words if I have the entry point to the program ( called index.js)
and I have a list of dependencies:

**index.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const connection = new Sequelize("jsfsa", "root", "password");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const session = require('client-sessions');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
const csrf = require("csurf");

// .....etc....
```

and then I have a route ( lets say a post route ) that is referenced in an external file:

**routes/login.js**

```
exports.submitLogin = (req, res) => {
   // do a bunch of stuff that requires the dependencies referenced in index.js
}
```

I can't figure out how reference any dependencies without just placing the needed module "requires" in the routes file.

**routes/login.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const connection = new Sequelize("jsfsa", "root", "password");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const session = require('client-sessions');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
const csrf = require("csurf");

// .....etc....




exports.submitLogin = (req, res) => {
   // do a bunch of stuff that requires the dependencies referenced in index.js
}
```

I want to believe there is a way to place all the module references in a file `my_dependencies.js` and then simply reference the entire file from all the other pages in my application using a line of code as simple as a function call.

Curious if this is possible.

I've tried reading online how to deal with this issue and everything is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to just pass the dependency variables I need directly to the functions that handle that specific route. In your case :

**index.js** (or wherever your route is being defined)

```
app.post('/someRoute', require('routes/login').submitLogin(dependency1, dependency2));
//If you are using express.Router() to handle routes/sub-routes,
//then this line could be different
```

**routes/login.js**

```
exports.submitLogin = function(dependency1, dependency2)
    return function(req, res){
       // do a bunch of stuff that requires the dependencies referenced in index.js
    }
}
```

Of course, in this practice I'm banking on the fact that you're not going to use *every single dependency* in every function, which would defeat its point.
This also lets me pass other context or state dependent variables to my route handlers.

---

There is also the practice of simply putting your dependency variable in the `app` variable, like :

```
app.dependency=someobject;
```

While this would hypothetically let you access your dependency using `req.app.dependency1`, this practice is not recommended as it can interfere with the already existing children of the `app` object.